# Laravel: Create or update related model?

Tags: php, laravel, models

Please be gentle with me - I'm a Laravel noob.

So currently, I loop through a load of users deciding whether I need to update a related model (UserLocation).

I've got as far as creating a UserLocation if it needs creating, and after a bit of fumbling, I've come up with the following;

```
$coords = $json->features[0]->geometry->coordinates;  
$location = new UserLocation(['lat'=>$coords[1],'lng'=>$coords[0]]);  
$user->location()->save($location);
```

My issue is that one the second time around, the Location may want updating and a row will already exist for that user.

Is this handled automatically, or do I need to do something different?

The code reads like it's creating a new row, so wouldn't handle the case of needing to update it?

**Update - solution:**

Thanks to Matthew, I've come up with the following solution;

```
$location = UserLocation::firstOrNew(['user_id'=>$user->id]);
$location->user_id = $user->id;
$location->lat = $coords[1];
$location->lng = $coords[0];
$location->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should reference the [Laravel API Docs](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_firstOrNew). I don't think they mention these methods in the "regular docs" though so I understand why you may have not seen it.

You can use the models `firstOrNew` or `firstOrCreate` methods.

> **firstOrNew:**  Get the first record matching the attributes or instantiate 
>   it.
>
> **firstOrCreate:** Get the first record matching the attributes or create it.

For Example:

```
$model = SomeModel::firstOrNew(['model_id' => 4]);
```

In the above example, if a model with a model_id of 4 isn't found then it creates a new instance of `SomeModel`. Which you can then manipulate and later `->save()`.  If it is found, it is returned.

You can also use `firstOrCreate`, which instead of creating a new Model instance would insert the new model into the table immediately.

So in your instance:

```
$location = UserLocation::firstOrNew(['lat'=>$coords[1],'lng'=>$coords[0]]);
```

$location will either contain the existing model from the DB or a new instance with the attributes `lat` and `lng` set to `$coords[1]` and `$coords[0]` respectively, which you can then save or set more attribute values if needed.

Another example:

```
$location = UserLocation::firstOrCreate(['lat'=>$coords[1],'lng'=>$coords[0]]);
```

$location will either contain the existing model from the DB or a new model with the attributes set again, except this time the model will have already been written to the table if not found.

Comment: Thanks, that's helped greatly in finding my solution - I've updated the OP.

Comment: Yea, that was a lifesaver for me when I learned of it as well :) glad to help.